# how to make separated data bases in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am building app for schools using HTML5, CSS3 and back end in Node.js and database in mySql. I want to place school data in separate tables/databases. like

```
School 1        school 2       
|______|        |______|   .....
schools could be 100 or more....
```

and on run time app determine from which data base it should get/insert data using user_id...? 
If I make a separate database containing data bases names with user_id's.
and every time app will check for data base name, establish connection to respective DB and get data. Would it be a good solution? 
Any suggestion...?

Comment: Questions asking for opinions is off topic for this site.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, but I would say that is not a good approach as it will become hard to maintain if you get hundreds of schools.  I would have a school table with foreign key constraints to tables holding the other data that cannot be normalised

Comment: Agree totally with Pete. You should have a schools database with your schools listed inside of it. This will make your queries far less complicated and more performant.

Comment: freshnode what did your exactly mean to "You should have a schools database with your schools listed inside of it". Did it mean that all schools data should be in only one table. lets in student table. all students related to school1,school2.. is in one student table?